Where can I find the details of swami Yogananda's 3 metal bracelet?
I recently started hearing about the 3 metal bracelet (copper, gold,silver) mentioned by Swami Yogananda in his book Autobiography of a Yogi.
I have the book, but I don't remember noticing that when I read the book and now I cant seem to find it when searching randomly. Wondering if maybe they removed it in later versions?
I would really appreciate if anyone could give me the chapter number / page number in the book where the details of this bracelet mentioned.
Thanks.
